# for testable controller do I need UoW or just repository?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I used to use Repository with Unit of Work patrons in my DAL. I m just starting working with MVC. Here I need some help please.

Do I need to implement Unit of Work in my DAL for making my controller testable  or just repository with Interface implementation is required ?

I m confuse how I will do controller unit tests if I implement UoW ?

Sorry my question may be a little theoretical but it is definite I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

A repository interface in your controller constructor is simple enough for controller testing.  If you want to also unit test repositories, you can use a unit of work interface to abstract the DB work, which is easy enough to create for EF.  That just allows you to test multiple layers.

Comment: thanks
You have said something I m looking to do actually but there is something I m not aware of.
If I use UoW, controller testing will not became difficult ? In test class how I will pass DB ? Populating Interface will became very difficult. Can you please suggest some link or kindly share more details.

Comment: If I will use repository itnerface in controlelr consturtor, controller testign will fine. I don't understand using a UoW interface how I will test controller and DAL ? Please guide.

Comment: Controller should consume Repository, but repository should consume UOW - therefore, the controller knows about ICustomerRepository, and CustomerRepository (the implementation) knows about the UOW.  Keep the controller and UOW separate.  Any CRUD operations would always go through the repository.  If you keep it separate, it will be much easier to work with.

Comment: thanks again. Just to clarify in controller I will instantiate interface of repository or interface of UoW ?

Comment: Repository interface; that will make it easy to mock database access using any mock tool.